# How to make make a margin-bottom in the headline?

Tags: html, css, frontend

The following code snippet shows my wished position for my headline in the footer.

```css
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
            /*HEADER*/
        .header{
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 91px;
            background-color: #000000;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .header a {
            color: #34E034;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .header a.logo {
            font-family: Wiz;
            font-size: 55px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }


        html, body {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
```

```html
 <div class = "header">
        <div class="header-row">
            <div class="left-main-header">
                <div class="header-box">
                    <div class="new-header">Techwizards</div>
                    <a class="logo"><b>Techwizards</b></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If I now wanna add a font style for the headline. This one:

```
@font-face {
        src: url("fonts/MagicSchoolTwo.ttf");
        font-family: wiz;
    }
```

I don't have margin to the bottom like in this picture.[image]

I tried everything - margin, padding but I don't get the space to the bottom. How can I fix that?

Comment: In your code there is no margin or padding....

Comment: Sure because I deleted it. If it is not working why I should put it in the code? Where should I add padding/margin that it works?

Comment: you have a fixed height on your header with the overflow hidden, that's probably why your padding isn't working

Comment: Also if I remove overflow hidden it is not working.

Comment: Try to add `.header { display: flex; align-items: flex-end; }` or increase line-height for .logo.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed Your Code:

You had an absolute height on your header. Then an "a" tag can't have a margin on default, you have to set it on display block to render the margin. I also added display flex to your header as suggested in the comments.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/yourbraineatsyou/pen/WNOJVVd)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*HEADER*/
.header {
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.header a {
  color: #34e034;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header a.logo {
  font-family: Wiz;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-row">
    <div class="left-main-header">
      <div class="header-box">
        <div class="new-header">Techwizards</div>
        <a class="logo"><b>Techwizards</b></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```